# bash profile error: not a valid identifier

Tags: python, bash

Whenever I open my bash profile I am immediately greeted with:

```
Last login: Wed Jul 27 11:41:49 on ttys000
-bash: PATH: command not found
-bash: export: `“/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/Layer0:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/Layer1:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/ModLib:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/Pythonstuff”': not a valid identifier
~.bash_profile
```

Here is my bash profile:

```
PATH="~/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
PATH = “/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit-ckopus”
export PATH
export PATH PYTHONPATH= “/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/Layer0:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/Layer1:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/ModLib:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/Pythonstuff”
export PYTHONPATH

PATH=${PATH}:${PYTHONPATH}
export PATH


echo '~.bash_profile'
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: you can't use spaces around the = sign for one

Comment: You seem to be using `“` instead of `"`.

Comment: quotes on line 3 seem a little weird. Those aren't the proper quotes to surround a string.

Comment: I thought they looked weird too, but when I delete them and re-type the quotes, they still appear the same. @MorganThrapp how do you go between each type?

Comment: @alli Your keyboard must be using an alternative locale. This should really go on unix.se

Comment: Keyboard using an alternative locale, eh? What program are you editing this file in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems there. The one giving you the error there is the quotes you're using: `“foo”` should be `"foo"`.

Your next issue is that you'll be losing your original path through the options there. You probably want something like:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:/usr/bin:${PATH}";
PATH="/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit-ckopus:${PATH}";
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}";
export PATH;

PYTHONPATH="/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/Layer0:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/Layer1:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit4/pbin/ModLib:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/Pythonstuff:${PYTHONPATH}";
export PYTHONPATH;
```

You also cannot use `~` to refer to home when assigning `PATH`, instead you should be using `$HOME`.

Comment: do you know how to go between the different types of quotes?

Comment: Also, `~` cannot be quoted in the assignments.

Comment: @chepner You are 100% right there. I noted it at first, but forgot to change it  when copying and pasting from the OP. Updated answer.

Comment: @alli, This was asked in a comment on the question, but what are you using to edit the files? Any kind of rich text editor will default to the styled quotes.

Comment: Just for completeness, you can still use `~` as long as it isn't quoted; the shell expands it if it is the first unquoted character following the `=` or an assignment or following a `:` in the value of an assignment.

Comment: btw, `export` is only needed for variables that aren't *already* flagged for export. `PATH` is already going to be in the environment before your `.bashrc` is run, so updates to it will be reflected in the environment already.

Comment: I finally used nano to edit the bash instead of a text editor and it worked after a few tries, however I did not implement the $HOME and it is no longer giving me the error - I will try this for completeness

Answer (score 1):

Below line is not correct

```
PATH = “/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit-ckopus”
```

It should be something like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit-ckopus"
```

1. remove the spaces around `=`
2. replace your double quotes `”` to `"`
3. you cannot replace `PATH` to `/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl/sfit-ckopus`, you need to **append** it to your `PATH`

Here's a bash profile sample online, you can read it and modify your own profile [Mac OS bash profile sample](https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/)

Comment: how to you go between the types of quotes?

Comment: @alli  I have 2 text inputs: English and Chinese.  Switch to English input when modify profile

Comment: @alli, `""` are the only quotes any proper UNIX text editor will insert. If you avoid using programs that aren't meant to act as text editors for editing text, you won't see any other kind.

Comment: I went to system preferences and mine says it only has U.S. English...

Comment: What program are you actually using to edit this file? Emacs? vim? gedit? ...? -- this is the kind of bug you would get if you were using Microsoft Word (or pasting from the clipboard content originally written by someone who did).